# Django, UserChangeForm errors

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm making a custom user form where a user can go in to change some details. It got two errors that I cannot understand what the problem is though.

The first problem is that the form doesn't fill out the user details. And it seems to be because `self` is empty when form is initialized, why?

And the second problem is that when I submit this form, it will complain about some KeyError, which I don't get either. I've pasted the code and stacktrace.

### Trackback

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/settings/

Django Version: 1.4
Python Version: 2.7.2
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'social_auth')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "c:\tools\python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.4-py2.7.egg\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "c:\tools\python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.4-py2.7.egg\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  20.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\xampp\htdocs\tddd27_project\contact\views.py" in settings
  47.       if form.is_valid():
File "c:\tools\python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.4-py2.7.egg\django\forms\forms.py" in is_valid
  124.         return self.is_bound and not bool(self.errors)
File "c:\tools\python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.4-py2.7.egg\django\forms\forms.py" in _get_errors
  115.             self.full_clean()
File "c:\tools\python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.4-py2.7.egg\django\forms\forms.py" in full_clean
  270.         self._clean_fields()
File "c:\tools\python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.4-py2.7.egg\django\forms\forms.py" in _clean_fields
  290.                     value = getattr(self, 'clean_%s' % name)()
File "c:\tools\python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.4-py2.7.egg\django\contrib\auth\forms.py" in clean_password
  122.         return self.initial["password"]

Exception Type: KeyError at /settings/
Exception Value: 'password'
```

### views.py

```
def settings(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserProfileForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponse("Change success")
    else:
        form = UserProfileForm(instance=request.user)
    return render_to_response('settings.html',{'form': form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

### forms.py

```
class UserProfileForm(UserChangeForm):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name')
        exclude = ('password',)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserProfileForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.instance  and self.instance.pk:
            self.fields['username'] = self.instance.username
            self.fields['first_name'] = self.instance.first_name
            self.fields['last_name'] = self.instance.last_name
```

### template

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Settings
{% endblock title %}

{% block content %}
 {{ user.username }}
    <form action="" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 6):

Regarding your second problem, I also came across the same issue today, while updating from Django 1.3 to Django 1.4. I had a custom form just like you:

```
class UserProfileForm(UserChangeForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', )
```

I solved the problem by adding a `clean_password` method like this:

```
class UserProfileForm(UserChangeForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', )

    def clean_password(self):
        return "" # This is a temporary fix for a django 1.4 bug
```

Answer (score 3):

> The first problem is that the form doesn't fill out the user details.
>   And it seems to be because self is empty when form is initialized,
>   why?

This is initiating a new blank modelform: `UserProfileForm()` or `UserProfileForm(request.POST)`

This is initiating a modelform bound to the user instance: `UserProfileForm(instance=request.user)` or `UserProfileForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)`.

If you don't fully understand this, please read the [documentation about ModelForm usage](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform).

In your view, you are instantiating new blank forms, instead of forms bound to the request.user instance. e.g. this `UserProfileForm(request.POST)` should be `UserProfileForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)`

Then, this is absolutely not necessary:

```
   if self.instance  and self.instance.pk:
        self.fields['username'] = self.instance.username
        self.fields['first_name'] = self.instance.first_name
        self.fields['last_name'] = self.instance.last_name
```

This doesn't fix the KeyError, but you should change:

```
exclude = ('password')
```

To:

```
exclude = ('password',)
```

Note that in the second case, exclude is a tuple. See this example in python shell:

```
In [1]: ('foo')
Out[1]: 'foo'

In [2]: ('foo',)
Out[2]: ('foo',)
```

As for your KeyError, well  I'm really unsure. I can [see the problem](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L121) but I've not cracked how it's supposed to work yet. Anyhow, if password is excluded, this function should not be run anyway.

Comment: I have changed to so exclude is a tuple now, but it still will complain about `KeyError`. It didn't work either to pass `instance=request.user` to `UserChangeForm`. Do I need to pass it to the view first before passing it to the UserChangeForm?

Comment: I have no idea what you are doing, sorry ... Maybe you should update the code in your topic ? Also maybe you should define what "didn't work" means ? Also maybe you could paste the full trackback ? That would be fantastic !

Comment: Sorry for my poor explain. I did anyhow made change to my question with updated code and added trackback now.

Comment: Thanks for the code update. I see that you didn't understand instance= very well so I elaborated on that, hope you make it !

Comment: I think you should first try to get your form to work without extending UserChangeForm. Like this: UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm)

Comment: I changed the form using `ModelForm` as you suggested http://dpaste.com/721684/. I also removed the init part. This one works and initiates the values. So it seems I didn't have to use `__init__()` to fill out the form with values? I don't understand...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9337/discussion-between-starcorn-and-jpic)

Answer (score 0):

```
class UserProfileForm(UserChangeForm):
class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', )

def clean_password(self):
    return self.clean_password
```

This will solve the issue. Hope this helps.